# $f$ is non-increasing implies $f'\le 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

I attempted this some time ago and was told my original proof was incorrect. Here's the new proof.
The question we are asked is "$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, if $f$ is non-increasing does this imply $f'\le 0$?"

Proof:

Take $x,y \in [a,b]$ we wish to show that for all $x \in (a,b)$ we have that $f'(x)\le 0$.
Suppose without loss of generality that $x<y \implies f(x) \ge f(y)$, then it is true that $f(y)-f(x) \le 0$.

We also know that $y-x >0$ as $y>x$.
Therefore we have that $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le0$. As we let $y \rightarrow x$ we see that $f'(x)\le 0$ as required.

Comment: It is very good...but you've only proved the right-sided derivative is non-negative, as you took only the case $\;y\to x\;,\;\;y>x\;$ ...! (this is the right-sided limit that defines the derivative) But now I bet you know what to do.

Comment: @DonAntonio just include the case $y<x$, I assume?

Comment: Exactly so...and it is very similar to what you already did, indeed. And then you'll have both two sided limits, and since THE limit exists (because it is given the function is differentiable), you're then done.

Comment: Okay thank you for your time, this helps.